# ndarray: Is there an effective way to swap 2 row/cols/etc. in different arrays?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

Using [ndarray](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray) with 2 `Array` structs, is there an effective way to swap 2 rows/cols/(slices along some axis)?

The title really sums up the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While different people might mean different things by "effective", a straightforward way is to assign the rows/columns to each other by means of a temporary. Here is an example for two rows ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)):

```
let mut a = arr2(&[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]);
let mut b = arr2(&[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]);
let mut a_row = a.slice_mut(s![1, ..]);
let mut b_row = b.slice_mut(s![2, ..]);
let tmp = a_row.to_owned();
a_row.assign(&b_row);
b_row.assign(&tmp);
println!("a = {:?}", a);
println!("b = {:?}", b);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`azip!()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/macro.azip.html) to swap elementwise and avoid creating a temporary array, or even [`par_azip!`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/macro.par_azip.html) to parallelize the copying.